# Use Windows Batch File to start a Java program

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am not familiar with batch script, but I want to create a Windows Batch File to start a Java program. The problem is that it has to specific the path where JRE is installed. When you install both JRE7 and JRE8, the name of that JRE8 folder would call something like *jre1.8.0_20* or *jre1.8.0_40* with the version number in the back. When you have only JRE8 installed, the folder would call *jre8*. Is there an easier way to find where the most updated JRE installed and then execute it? Thanks.

```
start ..\..\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Djna.library.path=.\lib -cp example.jar; com.example.main
```

Comment: Here is the working codes: javaw -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Djna.library.path=.\lib -cp example.jar; com.example.main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the location of `javaw.exe` by executing `where java`. This can be set as a variable inside a batch file like this:

```
# sets a variable called 'java' to the location of javaw.exe
for /f "delims=" %a in ('where javaw') do @set java=%a
# execute you jar file
%java% -jar <app.jar>
```

Noticed that the above only seems to work when running directly from the command line. Here is another example that should work in a batch file:

```
# run.bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ('where javaw') do (
  set java=%%a
)
!java! -jar %1
```

The above batch file should be called with the name of the `jar` file:

```
 run.bat app.jar
```

Comment: Hi Cyclone, thanks for the hint. What happen if user installs multiple different versions of Java? If we simply just look for javaw.exe then execute the Java jar file, it may mess up something right? Should not we always target the most updated version to avoid users running into error? When I try to run the commands above, it gives me the following error: Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required. I first installed JRE7 then installed JRE8. However, I keep both versions on my PC. Thanks for any help.

Comment: My guess would be that `where javaw` would return the path to the newest installed program ie the same program that will be executed if you just type `javaw -jar app.jar` at the commandline. For instance in my case `where javaw` will return `c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\Javapath\javaw.exe` which really is a symbolic link to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\javaw.exe`. If I look in this directory I also have `jre6` and `jre7` installed, but `jre1.8.0_40` is the latest one.

Comment: Thank you Cyclone for your quick reply! I will accept your answer because it works well for me. Thanks for letting me know "where javaw" and "javaw" simply do the trick.

Comment: @CaoFelix - Glad to help, notice that you can always use `where <appname>` when searching for a path to an executable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to just user JAVA_HOME and/or JRE_HOME and let the user / sysadmin worry what's installed.